# writing and appending to excel from pandas dataframe not working

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to write pandas dataframe (allagents) to excel sheet...If the file is not there it should create a new file and if file is already there, it should append the data at the end. Below is my code..

```
try:
    output_file = "all_agents_file.xlsx"
    # try to open an existing workbook
    book = load_workbook(output_file)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file)
    writer.book = book
    # copy existing sheets
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
    # read existing file
    previous_data = pd.read_excel(output_file)

    # write out the new sheet
    if not all_agents.empty:
        all_agents.index = np.arange(len(previous_data) + 1,
                                     len(previous_data) + len(all_agents) + 1)
        all_agents.to_excel(writer, index=True, header=False,
                            startrow=len(previous_data) + 1)
    writer.close()

except Exception as e:
    all_agents.index = np.arange(1, len(all_agents) + 1)
    all_agents.to_excel(output_file)

    print("File Created and Data Written in it...:", e)
```

The issue is it shows Exception like File is not a recognised excel file and if I specify engine="openpyxl" while reading, it gives Exception as File is not a zip file, if I give engine as "xlsxwriter", it gives exception as unknown engine xlsxwriter pandas==1.2.5, openpyxl==3.0.7

My machine is Ubuntu and the same code works on Jupyter notebook on my machine....But does not work when I run through terminal.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you run `!which python` in Jupyter and `which python` in the terminal and add both outputs to the question? Seems that you're using different `python` in each part.

Comment: If those are different, try running `pip install XlsxWriter` or `pip3 install XlsxWriter` in the terminal and run again with `xlsxwriter` engine.

Comment: Thanks for your time...Jupyter uses python 3.8.3 and terminal uses python 3.8.0. I tried re-installing xlsxwriter which I already had installed earlier and executed with xlsxwriter engine, but it shows File is not recognized excel file when I execute for second time...For first time it writes

Comment: What does " it shows File is not recognized excel file" exactly means? An error in Excel app? Some exception in the code?

Comment: It is the Exception when i execute the code...As you see my code, I have used try and except. So it goes in exception block and prints the exception ('e' in my code)

Comment: Can you run `!which python` in Jupyter and `which python` in the terminal and show us the results? Seems that there's a version problem. Are you using virtual environments or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I have created a virtual environment as well... when executed in jupyter notebook it shows the one installed on my machine "/usr/bin/python" and after activating virtual environment in terminal, it shows the complete path of my virtual environment "....../virtual_env_folder/bin/python"

Comment: I don't know what else to recommend. Seems a library problem. Run `!pip freeze` in Jupyter and `pip freeze` in the terminal to check both..

Comment: Thanks @bruno-uy for your efforts, I too feel like a library problem only...as said I have different versions in Jupyter and terminal. I will make terminal's version same as Jupyter. Thanks